# How to fix the issue of getting a black square while compressing PNG image using Huffman code?

Tags: c, huffman-code

I am writing a program that converts PNG image into the text by using Huffman code(It's like a compressed file) and after decompressed this file by using a CodeDictionary and as result I should get the same PNG image. But something going wrong and regardless which image would be chosen I get a black square. I need to use only Huffman code to get a compressed image.

Could anyone please suggest what should I do?

This is the code I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "../stb_image/stb_image.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "../stb_image/stb_image_write.h"


typedef struct Node {
    unsigned char symbol;
    int frequency;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
} Node;

Node *createNode(unsigned char symbol, int frequency) {
    Node *node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->symbol = symbol;
    node->frequency = frequency;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

Node *buildHuffmanTree(int *frequency) {
    // Создание начального массива узлов-листьев
    Node *leaves[256];
    int leafCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] > 0) {
            leaves[leafCount] = createNode(i, frequency[i]);
            leafCount++;
        }
    }

    // Построение дерева Хаффмана
    while (leafCount > 1) {
        // Поиск двух узлов с минимальной частотой
        int min1 = 0;
        int min2 = 1;
        if (leaves[min1]->frequency > leaves[min2]->frequency) {
            int temp = min1;
            min1 = min2;
            min2 = temp;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < leafCount; i++) {
            if (leaves[i]->frequency < leaves[min1]->frequency) {
                min2 = min1;
                min1 = i;
            } else if (leaves[i]->frequency < leaves[min2]->frequency) {
                min2 = i;
            }
        }

        // Создание нового узла-родителя
        Node *parent = createNode(0, leaves[min1]->frequency + leaves[min2]->frequency);
        parent->left = leaves[min1];
        parent->right = leaves[min2];

        // Удаление использованных узлов и добавление нового узла в массив листьев
        leaves[min1] = parent;
        leaves[min2] = leaves[leafCount - 1];
        leafCount--;
    }

    return leaves[0]; // Возвращение корня дерева
}

void createCodeDictionary(Node* root, unsigned char* code, int depth) {
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        printf("Symbol: %c, Code: ", root->symbol);
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            printf("%d", code[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        code[depth] = 0;
        createCodeDictionary(root->left, code, depth + 1);
        code[depth] = 1;
        createCodeDictionary(root->right, code, depth + 1);
    }
}

void compressImage(const unsigned char* symbol_sequence, size_t pixel_count, Node* root, unsigned char* compressed_data, size_t* compressed_size) {
    unsigned char* output = compressed_data;
    size_t output_bit_count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < pixel_count * 3; i++) {
        Node* current = root;
        unsigned char symbol = symbol_sequence[i];

        while (current->left != NULL && current->right != NULL) {
            int bit = (symbol >> (7 - output_bit_count)) & 1;

            if (bit == 0) {
                current = current->left;
            }
            else {
                current = current->right;
            }

            output_bit_count++;
            if (output_bit_count == 8) {
                *output = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    *output |= ((compressed_data[i] >> (7 - j)) & 1) << j;
                }
                output++;
                output_bit_count = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    *compressed_size = output - compressed_data;
}

void decompressImage(unsigned char* compressed_data, size_t compressed_size, Node* root, unsigned char* decompressed_data, size_t pixel_count) {
    unsigned char* output = decompressed_data;
    size_t output_bit_count = 0;
    Node* current = root;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < compressed_size; i++) {
        unsigned char byte = compressed_data[i];

        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            int bit = (byte >> j) & 1;

            if (bit == 0) {
                current = current->left;
            }
            else {
                current = current->right;
            }

            if (current->left == NULL && current->right == NULL) {
                *output = current->symbol;
                output++;
                output_bit_count++;

                if (output_bit_count == pixel_count * 3) {
                    return;
                }

                current = root;
            }
        }
    }
}

void freeHuffmanTree(Node *node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    freeHuffmanTree(node->left);
    freeHuffmanTree(node->right);
    free(node);

}



void printRGBFrequency(const int *frequency) {
    printf("Frequency of R, G, B:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 3) {
        printf("R:%d, G:%d, B:%d\n", frequency[i], frequency[i + 1], frequency[i + 2]);
    }
}



int main(void)
{
    // added block for getting information about the image into the memory
    int height, width, channels;
    unsigned char *image_data = stbi_load("../images/photo.png", &width, &height, &channels, 0);
    if (image_data == NULL){
        printf("Error in loading the image\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // convertion image data into a sequence of characters (RGB)
    unsigned char *pixels = image_data;
    size_t pixel_count = width * height;
    char *symbol_sequence = malloc(pixel_count * 3);
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < pixel_count; i++, j += 3) {
        symbol_sequence[j] = pixels[j]; // sequence of R        
        symbol_sequence[j + 1] = pixels[j + 1]; // sequence of G
        symbol_sequence[j + 2] = pixels[j + 2]; // sequence of B
    }

    // counting the frequency of occurence of each symbol
    int frequency[256] = {0}; 
    for (i = 0; i < pixel_count * 3; i++) 
        frequency[symbol_sequence[i]]++;
    
    printRGBFrequency(frequency);

    // start of making Haffman Tree

    Node* root = buildHuffmanTree(frequency);

    unsigned char code[256];
    createCodeDictionary(root, code, 0);

    // Compress image

    size_t compressed_data_size = (pixel_count * 3 * 8) / 8 + 1; // Assuming each symbol is represented by 8 bits
    unsigned char* compressed_data = malloc(compressed_data_size);
    compressImage(symbol_sequence, pixel_count, root, compressed_data, &compressed_data_size);

    // Save to txt

    FILE* file = fopen("../images/compressed_data.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fwrite(compressed_data, 1, compressed_data_size, file);
    fclose(file);

    // Read txt 

    file = fopen("../images/compressed_data.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    unsigned char* read_compressed_data = malloc(file_size);
    fread(read_compressed_data, 1, file_size, file);
    fclose(file);

    // Decompression of image

    unsigned char* decompressed_data = malloc(pixel_count * 3);
    decompressImage(read_compressed_data, file_size, root, decompressed_data, pixel_count);

    // Write image

    stbi_write_png("../images/decompressed_image.png", width, height, channels, decompressed_data, width * channels);


    // Free memory
    
    free(symbol_sequence);
    freeHuffmanTree(root);
    free(compressed_data);
    free(read_compressed_data);
    free(decompressed_data);
    stbi_image_free(image_data);






    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to rewrite the code several times by using other libraries to read the image, but got the same result.

Comment: Aside: a PNG image is already compressed using a combination of LZ77 and Huffman coding. How much better are you hoping to compress it with your own Huffman coding?

Comment: Break the task into three parts. Part 1: create and read a PNG file using the library.  Make sure that you can create a valid PNG file from known pixels. And then make sure that when you read that file, you get the same pixels in memory. Part 2: create a small file with known character frequencies, then Huffman code it. Make sure that the Huffman tree is correct, that the compressed file looks right, and that decompressing produces the same data that you started with. Part 3: combine part 1 and part 2.

Comment: Are you sure this: `int bit = (symbol >> (7 - output_bit_count)) & 1;` is the correct way to look up `symbol` in your Huffman tree? This looks like the decoding step, instead.

Comment: Print out (or use a debugger to inspect) the first few bytes of the source image and the compressed data. Do you get the correct binary code for your first symbols?